# I am not seeing iPhone 6, 6S sizes in bottom side in Auto Layout section in Xcode to adjust my view. I just see 4s, SE, 7 and 7 Plus sizes

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, size, simulator

I am not seeing iPhone 6, 6S sizes in the bottom side in AutoLayout section in Xcode to adjust my view. I just see 4s, SE, 7 and 7 Plus sizes.

Where can I find the other iPhone size views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because, the iPhone 6, iPhone 6S, iPhone 8 has the same resolution as iPhone 7, and also iPhone 6+, iPhone 6S+, iPhone 8+ has the same resolution as iPhone 7+.

If you want to check the behavior on iPhone 6, 6S, Please run the build on Simulator by selecting target device as iPhone6, iPhone6S and so on.

Hope it helps!