# How can I add a new device in Xcode 9?

Tags: ios, xcode9

How do I add a new device in Xcode? I need the iPhone 6 device. In the simulator, I have that device, but in Xcode is missing, how can I add the device here, in the red area?

[image]

Comment: Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42777320/1025063)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45633454/5301953 similar question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need iPhone 6 there explicitly. All that is important here is the screen size, and iPhones 5, 6, 7 & SE all had the same size screens. It's the one listed as iPhone SE.

Comment: Thank you very much! Have a great day!